# How to use clang-tidy configuration?

Tags: clang

I cannot use clang-tidy configuration correctly, it always ends up with no output. I use clang-3.9.

If I activate all the checks, it gets me 2752 lines:

```
clang-tidy test/src/inv.cpp -checks '*' -header-filter '.*' | wc -l  
2752
```

I then dump the config:

```
clang-tidy test/src/inv.cpp -checks '*' -header-filter '.*' -dump-config > .clang-tidy
```

And then I try to use it:

```
clang-tidy test/src/inv.cpp -config ''
```

and it yields no output at all...

The configuration looks OK. 
How should the clang-tidy configuration be used ?

Comment: I can not reproduce this problem, using `LLVM version 4.0.0svn-r277264`. Try the `-explain-config` option.

Comment: @JohanLundberg When I use -explain-config, it shows that most tests are enabled in the config and that some are enabled in the clang-tidy binary, but still nothing is output. I can confirm this on two projects.